# postgresql - one field split into different fields and get their count and sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

As you can see my DEMO SQL, that is what I want result.

I am curious, is there any better way to achieve this?

DEMO : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/23b5f3/2

Raw Data

```
  SELECT  name, drunk
  FROM tbl
```

[image]

1st Group By

```
  SELECT
    name,
    CASE drunk
      WHEN 'Y' THEN count(drunk)
      ELSE 0
    END as drunk,
    CASE drunk
      WHEN 'N' THEN count(drunk)
      ELSE 0
    END as awake
  FROM tbl  
  GROUP BY name, drunk
```

[image]

2nd Group By

```
SELECT
  b.name,
  sum(b.drunk) as drunk,
  sum(b.awake) as awake
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    CASE drunk
      WHEN 'Y' THEN count(drunk)
      ELSE 0
    END as drunk,
    CASE drunk
      WHEN 'N' THEN count(drunk)
      ELSE 0
    END as awake
  FROM tbl  
  GROUP BY name, drunk
) b
GROUP BY b.name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN drunk = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as drunk,
    SUM(CASE WHEN awake = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as awake
FROM
    tb1
GROUP BY
    name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use expressions inside aggregation functions and spare the subquery (which IIRC postgres planner is not super good at getting rid of):

```
select name,
       count(case when drunk = 'Y' then 1 end) as drunk,
       count(case when drunk = 'N' then 1 end) as awake
 from tbl
group by name;
```

(here I use `count`, but `sum` would be as good)